# Rebuild interface to change the language (GTK)

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am beginning to work on a program in which i want multilingual support, but since it is pretty modular (and i want it to be even more in the future), a language change means "destroy what you had of interface and build again with the content which language modules have". (You can see the source as of now on [GitHub](https://github.com/TrueXorFalse/Claurstrum/tree/51561e231075f526eff083b40b397d8333dbd9a9))

This full-modular approach may give many problems, but i still want it, and so the problem is: Whenever i destroy the widgets i had, until i am alone with the raw Gtk.Window itself, i am not able to assign once again widgets to it. They won't get displayed at all, sometimes silently, sometimes with errors depending on my approach.

1. Lets suppose the class window, which inherits from a Gtk.Window.
2. This class is the raw window, and i assign to it a Gtk.Box -
   self.interface.
3. self.interface itself, has two Gtk.Box's, one sidebar and one stack of contents.

> To rebuild i tried to:

- Change the language variable
- Use the method destroy on self.interface, which removes the widget and its child's.
- Reuse the function to build the widgets stack on top of self.interface
- Re-add self.interface to self (window).

This approach returns:

> g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>     Gtk.main()

Pointing to the .show_all() method in [this file](https://github.com/TrueXorFalse/Claurstrum/blob/51561e231075f526eff083b40b397d8333dbd9a9/__main__.py).

I've already tried to leave interface without using .destroy on it, applying only on its child's, and then creating them again over it, but didn't worked. The window was left blank with no error at all.

The code i am trying right now is:

```
#Remember, self is a Gtk.Window()
def __init__(self):
    [...]
    self.interface = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
    self.stack = None
    self.add(interface)
    self.build_interface()

def build_interface(self):
    self.interface.pack_start(
            self.create_side_navigation(
                self.interface_data["menu"][self.language]["name"])
            , False, False, 0
        )
        self.stack = self.create_content_stack(self.interface_data["menu"][self.language])
        self.interface.pack_start(self.stack, True, True, 0)

###Code to rebuild(this is a question dialog):
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    self.language = self.new_language["Index"]
    self.new_language = None

    self.stack.destroy()
    self.interface.destroy()
    self.interface = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
    self.build_interface()
    self.add(self.interface)
```

This code will cause the previously told "g_object_unref" error.
What is causing this? Why can't i add anything once deleted?

Feel free to clone the repo and try, the code is well commented(yet i am not sure if poorly written, i am a python newbie) and its quite easy to understand where is the problematic part. Its not too big.

PS: It should need GTK+3.12 because of the popovers.

Answer (score 0):

As a GTK Dev showed to me, GTK has by default all the widgets invisible.

The error was caused in the line which declared the whole interface visibility (`windowclass.show_all()`), but since the interface changed since when it was applied, it threw that warning.

He pointed me to `.remove()` instead of `.destroy()`, and to set `.show_all()` to the new elements after set up.

The next commit(or the following) on that git, has the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be multilingual is to keep your widgets the same and merely change the text of labels and titles. This can be done without disturbing the overall setup. For example:

```
s='Stop'
if lang=='fr': s='Arret'
...
somelabel.set_label(s)
```